# JSF Binding component update before actionListener is called

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, binding, primefaces-mobile

I have a problem with a JSF Binding component.
My xhtml page has a panel group with a binding attribute.

```
<h:panelGroup binding="#{formularioBean.panelGroup}" layout="block" id="campoDinamico" />
```

The code in the baking bean is

```
public HtmlPanelGroup getPanelGroup() {
    HtmlPanelGroup panelGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();

    Field field = new Field();

    HtmlOutputText textoLabel = new HtmlOutputText();
    textoLabel.setValue(JSFUtils.getStringFromBundle("formulario.label.TEXTO_1"));
    textoLabel.setStyle("font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px");

    field.getChildren().add(textoLabel);

    int count = 0;
    for (String textoParcial : this.listaTextoSugerencia) {
        InputText input = new InputText();
        input.setId("id_tx" + count);
        input.setValue(textoParcial);
        input.setImmediate(true);
        count++;
        field.getChildren().add(input);
    }

    panelGroup.getChildren().add(field);
}
```

Below in the same form, i have a primefaces commandbutton

```
<p:commandButton value="Añadir" actionListener="#{formularioBean.addInputText}" update="campoDinamico"/>
```

My problem is when i click this button, the bingind component call his backing bean binding method before the actionListener is called.

How i prevent this and update after the actionListener finish?

I use primefaces 3.5, primefaces mobile 0.9.4, JSF 2 and the Bean is view scoped

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797231/why-does-postconstruct-callback-fire-every-time-even-though-bean-is-viewscoped and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026082/jsf-2-0-why-my-viewscope-beans-is-re-created-even-though-still-on-same-view and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215098/view-scoped-bean-recreated-on-post-when-url-parameters-not-used

Comment: Moreover, just use `<ui:repeat><h:inputText>` instead. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/how-to-dynamically-add-jsf-components/3409511#3409511